# PHP fetch from many to many

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have issue with this PHP function, i'm trying to fetch user with his roles and groups, its working good with roles, but i have issues with groups because i'm getting array with same groups and of course what i want is duplicate free array. I understand why i'm getting this, because my user have 2 roles and i get him in sql query 2 times, can anyone explain me what is best practice and how to avoid this, should i use query like this, or i can use anther query where i will find all groups for member and then just place it in that array, but that is 2 DB calls in one function and its probably not that good solution.

```
function getAll($mysqli) {
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT u.id, u.firstName, u.lastName, u.email, 
        u.phoneNumber, u.address, u.birthDate, ur.roleName, cg.id, cg.name FROM users as u 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN user_role as ur ON u.id = ur.userId 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN user_group as ug on ug.userId = u.id 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN control_group as cg on cg.id = ug.groupId");

    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $firstName, $lastName, $email, $phoneNumber, 
        $address, $birthDate, $roleName, $groupId, $groupName);
    $users = array();

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        if (empty($users[$id])) {
            $users[$id] = array(
                'id' => $id,
                'firstName' => $firstName,
                'lastName' => $lastName,
                'email' => $email,
                'phoneNumber' => $phoneNumber,
                'address' => $address,
                'birthDate' => $birthDate,
                'roles' => array(),
                'groups' => array()
            );
        }
        if ($roleName) {
            $users[$id]['roles'][] = array(
                'roleName' => $roleName
            );
        }
        if ($groupId) {
            $users[$id]['groups'][] = array(
                'groupName' => $groupName
            );
        }
    }

    $stmt->close();
    $mysqli->close();;
    echo json_encode($users);
}
```

When i execute that function i get response like this

```
{  
   "1":{  
      "id":1,
      "firstName":"John",
      "lastName":"Doe",
      "email":"john@email.com",
      "phoneNumber":"062-441234-123123",
      "address":"Some Address 40\/2",
      "birthDate":"1989-12-29",
      "roles":[  
         {  
            "roleName":"Admin"
         },
         {  
            "roleName":"User"
         }
      ],
      "groups":[  
         {  
            "groupName":"Group 1"
         },
         {  
            "groupName":"Group 1"
         }
      ]
   },
   "2":{  
      "id":2,
      "firstName":"Jane",
      "lastName":"Doe",
      "email":"jane@email.com",
      "phoneNumber":"0112-11121-221322",
      "address":"Address 21ca",
      "birthDate":"1975-12-28",
      "roles":[  
         {  
            "roleName":"Admin"
         },
         {  
            "roleName":"User"
         }
      ],
      "groups":[  

      ]
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check if a role (or a group) already exists before inserting it in the array:

```
if ($roleName) {
    $found = false;
    foreach ($users[$id]['roles'] as $role) {
        if($role['roleName'] == $roleName){
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if($found == false)
        $users[$id]['roles'][] = array(
            'roleName' => $roleName
        );
 }
```

Notice I gave you an answer based in your structure. But I would strongly advice to change the structure of the array to make the checking of the existence of the role as fast as `O(1)`

Edit: In order to complete my answer: I would say the JSON structure doesn't reflect what the real case is. You state a user has roles and groups, and that's true, but the roles belong to the group. A user can be an ADMIN in a Group 1 and ANYTHING in Group 2. That's why I think what you should really output is something like this:

```
{  
   "1":{  
      "id":1,
      "firstName":"John",
      "lastName":"Doe",
      "email":"john@email.com",
      "phoneNumber":"062-441234-123123",
      "address":"Some Address 40\/2",
      "birthDate":"1989-12-29",
      "groups":[  
         {  
            "groupName": "Group 1",
            "roles": [
                {  
                    "roleName":"Admin"
                },
                {  
                    "roleName":"User"
                }
            ]
         }

      ]
   },
   "2":{  
      "id":2,
      "firstName":"Jane",
      "lastName":"Doe",
      "email":"jane@email.com",
      "phoneNumber":"0112-11121-221322",
      "address":"Address 21ca",
      "birthDate":"1975-12-28",
      "groups":[  

      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: Roles are working fine, i have issues with groups, and im wondering why groups dont work like roles its basically same case

Comment: It won't work if you have a user with the same role in different groups. Try and you'll see how it also gets duplicated.

Comment: Also, If you want my honest opinion... Only by what I can look, I'm feeling wether the DB isn't reflecting your business logic or the structure of the JSON isn't (or both).

Comment: Ok got it, can you explain me what do you mean when you say that i should change structure, can you be more specific and if possible give code example of changed structure ?

Comment: I completed the answer.

Comment: Good thinking but its not the case here, actually if user is admin he have access to all groups and have all permisions, but i need gropus because users that have role user will have few groups where they can do some stuff in most cases they will have one or two groups and user role. I will have max 2 admins and they dont need to have groups at all, because they will automatically have full access to everything.  Does that means you will need to change your answer again ? :)

Comment: Then, do it as I said at the beginning. But I would reconsider rethinking the database because what you have right now and what you want aren't the same...